# PropertyInfo parameter with requirements

Tags: c#, reflection

Is it possible to take `PropertyInfo` (or something similar) as an argument and also require that the PropertyInfo be of type `decimal`? Or better yet require that it be a property of a specific class or interface? I'm thinking similar to how typescript has `keyof`

This is what I was hoping would work

```
public decimal SumProperty(Item item, PropertyInfo propertyOfItem){
    // has to be casted to decimal?
    return propertyOfItem.GetValue(item);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show expected usage?

Comment: But in general - you can't require the property to be of some type with current signature, but can check if it is with `PropertyInfo.PropertyType`. Also you can use property selector with `Func` - `SumProperty(Item item, Func<Item, decimal> selector)` and call it `selector(item)` (which in the provided case kind of beats the purpose).

Comment: In short, no, C# doesn't allows to limit the values of the classes, only of what class variables are. You can add the check at runtime, though.

Comment: An alternative could be to take a `Func<Item, decimal>`.

Comment: or if you **really** want a `PropertyInfo` you could extract it from `Expression<Func<Item, decimal>>`